# How to multiply two columns of a data file and add them in python?

Tags: python

I want to multiply the contents two columns of a file generated from a bash script and then add them up to get the summation. The problem is the file contains some special character on the last column which I cannot get rid of. How do I read the following file and multiply col. 3 and col. 5 and then add them up? I want to get sum = 4*821+3*28+4*1+6*1+5*13 ...

> 1. 0  0  4  0        821.00         95.02%
> 2. 0  0  3  0         28.00          3.24%
> 3. 0  1  4  0          1.00          0.12%
> 4. 0  0  6  0          1.00          0.12%
> 5. 0  0  5  0         13.00          1.50%

Normally I could have done it by

```
flist = glob.glob(filename)

fdata = []
for f in flist:
  load = np.loadtxt(f)
  fdata.append(load) 
  fdata_arry=np.array(fdata)

print fdata_arry

c = fdata_arry[:,2]*fdata_arry[:,4] 
d = np.sum(c)
```

but in this case the last col. has a %sign which makes it difficult to read. Is there a way to ignore the last column. This should be pretty basic but I'm just a new programmer so your help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Use the `usecols` option of `loadtxt` to specify which columns you want to load.

`np.loadtxt(f, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4))`

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
dat=open('dat','r')
reader= csv.reader(dat, delimiter=' ')
prod=0
for row in reader:
    prod+=float(row[2])*float(row[4])

prod
# 3443.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use read instead of loadtxt, you get each line as a string which is easy to manipulate, try something like the following,

```
import numpy as np

f = '/home/davcra/Desktop/test.txt'
fdata = []

with open (f, "r") as myfile:  
    data=myfile.readlines()

for i, line in enumerate(data):
    data[i] = line.strip('%\n').strip('\n').split(' ')
    data[i] = [float(d) for d in data[i]]

data = np.asarray(data)
print data
c = data[:,2]*data[:,4] 
d = c.sum()
```